# Monitor directory and if a file is requested then rsync on demand

Tags: filesystems, rsync, utilities, development

Is there a tool that monitors a certain directory and if a program tries to access a file in that directory, the program loads that file from another place transparently for any application that tries to load that file?

The background is that I have a local development environment for a large server application. At the moment, I sync all the files created by the users on the production system from time to time via `rsync` to my local machine. But the amount of data has become too big. I can not store the several hundreds of gigabytes from the production environment on my local dev machine. Is there a way of mimicking the files from the external system and load/sync them only from the external system if they are really needed?

Writing changes to these "monitored" directories should nevertheless take only place locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation sounds like a natural use for [unionfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS).  With unionfs you could mount the production system's data as a read-only filesystem and mount a transparent writable filesystem layer on top of it that would accept your local changes.

Comment: This sounds pretty interesting, I didn't know about that. Will devinitly give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be good solution to mount remote filesystem over network. There are many possibilities to achieve that.

You can export some directories from production machine over NFS, SMB or SSHFS and then mount it on your dev machine. If you use this method files will be transfered over network only if you request it.

I don't know what is a purpose to transfer users files from production system to dev system, but you should remember about security of this solution if files contains some private/sensitive data. If you choose option to mount remote file system remember to mount it in read only mode to avoid accidental destruction.

Comment: It's mainly image and print data as pdf's. And the reason to have it local is that I need to display the images in my local browser and that I generate PDF's with the image data. So you cannot work or especially hunt bugs if you have no data locally.

But anyway - just mounting a remote directory will not do it. I need do be able to operate on the files. But as you said it is not an option to write back to the productive (or staging or whatever) system (which holds the complete dataset) from local.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a job for [FS-Cache](https://people.redhat.com/%7Edhowells/fscache/). This is a Linux filesystem that interfaces between applications and the real filesystem (which can be NFS or SSHfs if you're caching remote files).

The quickstart guide:

```
cachefilesd
mount -t nfs -o fsc remotehost:/somedir /mount/point
ls /var/cache/fscache
```

For more information, see [The Fedora documentation](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/fscachemain.html), [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-fscache), [Bart's Blog](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/20090612215638), [old Gentoo wiki](http://wikigentoo.ksiezyc.pl/HOWTO_FS-Cache.htm). Also perhaps of interest, an old article about [CacheFS and FS-Cache](https://www.admin-magazine.com/HPC/Articles/Caching-with-CacheFS).

Comment: @roaima They're still in the Wayback machine. I found copies of the same articles elsewhere on the web. Looks like the Fedora documentation is still good.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for following that through

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in late here, but here's a solution that I use at work to sync any changes from host A > host B.

You can control the sync interval, i.e. if changes are detected within 30 sec, sync once every 30 sec, etc..

It has other options, checkout the README.

Similar to `lsyncd`, but much simpler config and uses very low memory/CPU.

[perfecto25](https://github.com/perfecto25)/[**poni**](https://github.com/perfecto25/poni)